# Is user logged in variable with PHP

Tags: php, oop, authentication

I've built a class called Login with a construct that either logs them in or it doesn't... I also have a static function called isAuthenticated which is meant to check if the user is logged in or not... I've been messing around with static functions etc but can't seem to get what I want.

Ideally, it'd be where I can easily go

```
<?php if (Login::isAuthenticated()) { ?>
<a href="/sign-out/">Sign Out</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Here is my class so far... Complete with my attempts..

```
class Login
 {
    private static $_auth;

    public function __construct($username, $rawPassword) {

        global $db;

        require('edit/users/config.php');

        $hashedPassword = sha1(SALT . $_POST['password']);

        $query = 'SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE user = "' . $db->cleanString($username) . '" AND pass = "' . $db->cleanString($hashedPassword) . '" LIMIT 1';


        $login = $db->query($query);

        if ($login) {


            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            self::$_auth = true;



            header('Location: ' . CONFIG_DIR_BASE);


        } else {

            ErrorHandler::addErrorToStack('Your username and/or password did not match one on our system. ');

        }

    }



    public static function isAuthenticated() {



         return self::$_auth;


    }







 }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here.  The question is a little unclear.

Comment: I can see what you're trying to do, but I don't see anything that's keeping it from working.  What's not working?

Comment: Where are you instantiating the Login class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since HTTP is stateless, your class' static variable ($_auth) won't 'survive' between pageloads, so if you're trying to make the variable stick, you'll need to store it as a [Session variable](https://www.php.net/session).

However, I would strongly encourage you to **not** write your own auth class unless you are *really* serious about it. There are dozens of excellent PHP auth scripts out there to pick from, that have already addressed all the [intricacies of web authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-website-authentication-beta).

Comment: Good eye.  Your isAuthenticated property could just check to see if the username is set.  If it's not, you're not logged in.  If it is, you're logged in.  Just make sure to clear it once you've logged off.

Comment: Thanks.. Think I'll use isset($_SESSION['username']) .. and I'll look into the auth classes.